# Transform Either<A, B>[] into Either<A[], B[]>

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

As the title says, I want to transform `Either<A, B>[]` into `Either<A[], B[]>`

The rule is, if there is a single left-value (an error), I want to get a left-value with all the errors; otherwise, I want the right answers.

This seems like it should be the easiest thing, but here is all I have:

```
const compress = <A, B>(arr: E.Either<A, B>[]): E.Either<A[], B[]> => 
  A.reduce(
    E.right([]),
    (acc: E.Either<A[], B[]>, v: E.Either<A, B>) => 
    E.match(
      (a: A) => E.match((aar: A[]) => E.left([...aar, a]), 
                        (bar: B[]) => E.left([a]))(acc),
      (b: B) => E.match((aar: A[]) => E.left(aar), 
                        (bar: B[]) => E.right([...bar, b]))(acc)
    )(v)
   )(arr);
```

Seems way too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [`separate`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Array.ts.html#separate) function which you can use to collect up the lefts and rights in an array of `Either`s. That could arguably be used as is, but you could get the exact type you're looking for by doing:

```js
import { separate } from 'fp-ts/Array';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

declare const es: Array<E.Either<number, string>>;

const output: E.Either<string[], number[]> = pipe(
  es,
  separate,
  // Assuming you want to have the either be left if any result was left.
  (s) => s.left.length > 0 ? E.left(s.left) : E.right(s.right),
);
```

There's also [`sequenceArray`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html#sequencearray) which can be a bit of a shortcut when you're aggregating errors from multiple sources, but this becomes a left as soon as a single left is encountered so you wouldn't get back all of the left values (which is a potential downside if you need to know all of the lefts at once).

```js
const output2: E.Either<string, readonly number[]> = pipe(
  es,
  E.sequenceArray,
);
```